# how can i avoid single quotation mark and parentheses?

Tags: python

```
def age_20():
        user_age= int(input("enter the age: "))
        if user_age >= 20:
            user_age= user_age - 20
            return (user_age, "20 years difference from now" )
        if user_age < 20:
            user_age= user_age + 20
            return (user_age, "20 years difference from now")
    print(age_20())
```

Return value shows: 
(5, '20 years difference from now')
        `how can i avoid single quotation mark and parentheses?`

Comment: You're returning a tuple. What should be the expected output ?

Comment: 5, 20 years difference from now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it stands, you are returning a tuple containing an int and a string.  If you want a single return you could use something like this instead:

```
return (str(user_age) + "20 years difference from now")
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(age_20()[1])`

Since you're returning a tuple, and assuming you only want to print the string. If you want to still print both,

```
age = age_20()
print(age[0],", ",age[1])
```